# epstopdf: Save converted files to directory where original file is saved

Tags: epstopdf

**Background:** I'm using the document class `memoir` in TexShop on a Mac. For my .eps images (that are all saved on different locations), I use the package `epstopdf`.

**Problem:** In the preamble, I specify use `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}`. That way all the coverted images get saved in the same directory as the .tex file. However, this gets very messy since I have many images. Is it possible to save the converted images at the same directory as the original images? Unfortunately, I have many different images and they saved at different locations. So, just specifying one other path in `\epstopdfsetup{}` will probably not work.

Answer (score 2):

If the folders that hold the EPS files are subfolders of the folder containing your `.tex` file, then `pdflatex` does this automatically, no need for the `epstopdf` package.

In this MWE, I have two EPS files, `A.eps` and `B.eps` in separate folders

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./A/}{./B/}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{A}

\includegraphics{B}

\end{document}
```

When I run this through `pdflatex` I get

```
A/A-eps-converted-to.pdf
B/B-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

Things get more complicated if A and B are not subfolders (security)

BTW: Since you are on a Mac, why don't you just convert the EPS' by hand (editors are not always good as showing warnings from EPS conversions).

On the Mac in a terminal,

```
for foo in *.eps ; do epstopdf $foo ; done
```

will convert all EPS files in the current folder.

Comment: I wonder why it is actually necessary to use `epstopdf` on a Mac anyway. AFAIK the conversion from `.eps` to `.pdf` happens at compile time automatically, assuming the OP uses MacTeX.

Comment: @naphaneal it is not, but the automatic conversion has some security settings that limits it, `epstopdf` often runs with `shell-escape` and this does not have the same limitations and this may have more flexibility. That said, I always perfer to convert by hand, because then **I** know what happend.